# Array subscript is not an integer error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Just wondering if anyone could help me with the following piece of code:

```
// Get uniform locations.
GLint m_nUniforms = 0;
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms, 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);


glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &m_nUniforms);
for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_nUniforms; i++)
{
    char *uniformName = NULL;
    GLint size;
    GLenum type;

    glGetActiveUniform(_program, i, max_length + 1, NULL, &size, &type, uniformName);
    uniforms[uniformName] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, uniformName);
}
```

I want to assign uniforms with a subscript of type 'char* uiformName' for every iteration of the for-loop. I'm receiving the error "Array subscript is not an integer".

How can I use a char as an array subscript?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What you want then is a dictionary where both the key and value are strings:

```
NSMutableDictionary *uniforms = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (blah)
{
    glGetActiveUniform(_program, i, max_length + 1, NULL, &size, &type, uniformName);
    char *uniform = glGetUniformLocation(_program, uniformName);
    [uniforms addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:uniform]
                 forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:uniformName]];
}
```